# What does tag implies in Alarm logs in Android?

Tags: android, logging, tags, alarmmanager

I'm trying to read the Alarm Manager logs on a device using ADB, for each alarm there is a filed named Tag. Can anyone explain what that tag means?

I ran adb shell dumpsys alarm.
It provided me with the list of all current alarms in queue to be fired.
Every Alarm has a tag. What that tag means and how to set value for that tag while creating alarm?

```
******-MacBook-Air-3:~ xyz$ export PATH="~/Library/Android/sdk/platform-tools":$PATH
******-MacBook-Air-3:~ xyz$ adb shell dumpsys alarm
Current Alarm Manager state:
  Settings:
    min_futurity=+1s0ms
    min_interval=+1m0s0ms
    listener_timeout=+5s0ms
    allow_while_idle_short_time=+1s0ms
    allow_while_idle_long_time=+9m0s0ms
    allow_while_idle_whitelist_duration=+10s0ms
  nowRTC=1546947850717=2019-01-08 17:14:10 nowELAPSED=160817
  mLastTimeChangeClockTime=1546947819004=2019-01-08 17:13:39
  mLastTimeChangeRealtime=+2m9s104ms
  Next non-wakeup alarm: -10s717ms = 2019-01-08 17:14:00
  Next wakeup: +9s268ms = 2019-01-08 17:14:19
  Last wakeup: -701ms set at -701ms
  Num time change events: 2
  mDeviceIdleUserWhitelist=[1000, 10097, 10188, 10208, 10309]
  Next alarm clock information: 
    user:0 pendingSend:false time:1546995600000 = 2019-01-09 06:30:00 = +13h15m49s283ms
  Pending alarm batches: 84
Batch{fac7508 num=1 start=170085 end=170085 flgs=0x9}:
    RTC_WAKEUP #0: Alarm{44674a1 type 0 when 1546947859984 com.samsung.android.spayfw}
      tag=*walarm*:LocationSensor
      type=0 whenElapsed=+9s268ms when=2019-01-08 17:14:19
      window=0 repeatInterval=0 count=0 flags=0x9
      operation=PendingIntent{f0ee6c6: PendingIntentRecord{b52b375 com.samsung.android.spayfw broadcastIntent}}
Batch{6ccc687 num=4 start=172775 end=178221 flgs=0x8}:
    RTC #3: Alarm{d17d9b4 type 1 when 1546947862674 com.wssyncmldm}
      tag=*alarm*:com.wssyncmldm/com.samsung.android.app.fotaclient.device.UpdateDeviceIntentService
      type=1 whenElapsed=+11s958ms when=2019-01-08 17:14:22
      window=+9h0m0s0ms repeatInterval=43200000 count=0 flags=0x8
      operation=PendingIntent{cb4b9dd: PendingIntentRecord{99838a0 com.wssyncmldm startService}}
```

Answer (score 0):

String: string describing the alarm. Basically used for logging and battery optimization from framework. So basically you can say this is identification of alarm.
It will take class name if not set. If you want custom name pass the string in set/setExact alarm manager api